# HTML pages in the Dropbox Public folder

Tags: html, audio, video, hyperlink, dropbox

I dearly hope my first question here is 'acceptable', but I cannot find an answer anywhere - not even from an online Dropbox search.

As a web developer in training, I recently added an HTML file to my Public folder in Dropbox; it is meant as an example webpage for my 'portfolio'. The rendered page directly in Dropbox online links to a Dropbox CSS file successfully. Also, my local Dropbox images link and display successfully.

However, my link to a Dropbox audio file does not play - and neither does the video link to Youtube.

All 'src' and 'a href' links work fine when I render the page from my laptop Desktop Dropbox app; they link to external pages and audio and video files correctly. After researching, I had already changed the 'www' to 'dl' to my local Dropbox files, but that doesn't solve the issue of links working when rendered from the Dropbox server. The audio file works fine when accessing the file directly in Dropbox online using the player, so it's the HTML file that cannot 'find' the audio file from within the Dropbox server. Similarly, any hyperlinks to external sites, such as Youtube and my Linkedin account do not work by left-clicking or CTRL-click - the correct URL shows in the bottom-left corner but the link does not respond. Only right-clicking and 'open in another tab' works on links, thus 'escaping' the restriction of the Dropbox server.

I tried to provide as much detail here as possible so that you're fully aware of my situation. I hope someone knows how to 'free' these hyperlinks from the Dropbox server. I'll soon have my first website online, which will eliminate these issues - but I'm curious to solve this Dropbox problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dropbox probably blocks requests to media that are embedded in a web page. I'd just use a proper hosting service. (Try [this](http://cantonbecker.com/work/musings/2014/how-to-directly-link-or-embed-dropbox-images/) before giving up though)

Comment: You're probably right about the blocking of requests. I'll check that out. Thank you for your rapid response Pekka. :-)

Comment: Thanks Pekka웃 for your assistance but unfortunately adding '?raw=1' at the end of the audio file does not help the audio file to render when the HTML file is accessed within Dropbox online. Thanks for trying.

Comment: No prob - then it's probably just not possible to embed content.

Comment: Can you update your question to add some sample code? This works for me: `<audio controls autoplay><source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbw9hfghk4pqqiw/Laughter.mp3?raw=1" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>`

Comment: @Greg - Thanks for your reply. my code for the audio link is: <audio src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5lfza67g4e16mc4/Escape.mp3?dl=0" autoplay></audio> but it's not just the audio as I explained in my question post. It's any links too ... they don't work from the online Dropbox. After hours of effort, I solved my problem by creating another folder called Public Access and adding all Dropbox links from Public to the new folder. Result: when you click the link, a new page says to click the button to open the file in a new tab and then the file works okay 'cause it's escaped Dropbox! :-)